# leaflet popup width on markers loaded with JSON

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, leaflet

I have a leaflet map with markers loaded **dynamically** with **geoJSON** data:

```
mapLayers.markets = L.geoJSON(geoData, {
    pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
        switch (feature.properties.status) {
            case "stress":
                return L.marker(latlng, { icon: iconA });
            case "alert":
                return L.marker(latlng, { icon: iconB });
            case "crisis":
                return L.marker(latlng, { icon: iconC });
        }
    },
    onEachFeature: onEachFeature,
}).addTo(map);
```

I bind the popup inside the *onEachFeature* function:

```
function onEachMarketFeature(feature, layer) {    
    var tableCommon = '<table>' +
        '<thead><tr><th>Agency</th><th>Personnel</th></tr></thead>' +
        '<tbody>' +
        '<tr><td>Alfa</td><td>12</td></tr>' +
        '<tr><td>Bravo</td><td>123</td></tr>' +
        '</tbody></table>';
    var tableSingle='<table>' +
        '<thead><tr><th>Agency</th><th>Personnel</th></tr></thead>' +
        '<tbody>' +
        '<tr><td>Juliet</td><td>62</td></tr>' +
        '<tr><td>Lima</td><td>41</td></tr>' +
        '</tbody></table>';

    var container = '<div><div class="row"><div class="col-xl-6">' + tableCommon + '</div><div class="col-xl-6">' + tableSingle + '</div></div></div>';

    layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.type +
        '<br/> Market Code=' + feature.properties.code + '<br/>' + feature.properties.name + '</a><br/>' + container);
}
```

The problem is that the content inside the popup, defined with row-col classes of **bootstrap4**, is greater than the popup and this one **is not resized** to fit it, and results of a smaller width.

I've tried to set in the **bindPopup** function the {maxWidth: "none"} but it's even worst and the popup is extra small.

This is what I get:

[image]

and this is what I'm trying to have:

[image]